# Trying to solve a problem using GUI, but if statements are confusing me

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a project but I'm stuck in a problem.

• Your program should display a menu that allows the user to do the
following operations (Note: use GUI):

1. Add a new customer
2. Delete a customer
3. Modify a customer’s information // this option must display a sub-menu as:

--------1. Individual customer //modify the basic info: phone #...
Code:

```
 //Modify Customer
    if (actionEvent.getSource().equals(modifyCustomer)) {
        frame.dispose();
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        individualCustomer = new JButton("Individual customer");
        individualCustomer.addActionListener(this);

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(individualCustomer);

        frame.setTitle("General Distribution Center");
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Individual Customer
        if (actionEvent.getSource().equals(individualCustomer)) {
            frame.dispose();
            System.out.println("Enter the new phone number: ");
            int updatedPhoneNumber = input.nextInt();
        }
```

My first problem is: Why the following if statement is false?

```
if (actionEvent.getSource().equals(individualCustomer)) {
```

My second problem is: When the if statement is true.. for example if I type:

```
if(true){
         frame.dispose();
         System.out.println("Enter the new phone number: ");
         int updatedPhoneNumber = input.nextInt();
     }
```

It runs this block immediately after I select Modify Customer option. Without showing Individual Customer option/button which I created here:

```
individualCustomer = new JButton("Individual customer");
individualCustomer.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: You have `actionEvent.getSource().equals(modifyCustomer)` and only if that is true do you then check `actionEvent.getSource().equals(individualCustomer)`. If the 1st one is true then the 2nd one can't be true.

Comment: I've always used individual listeners so I rarely had to make complex choices like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a *huge* ActionListener, one that is trying to do too many things at once. That second if-statement will never be true because of the way your code is wired. You've nested the if's such that if the outer if is true (allowing the inner if to be reached), the inner if will *always* be false:

```
if (actionEvent.getSource().equals(modifyCustomer)) {
    // if we're here, then source will **never** be individualCustomer

    //..... code here

    // the if-test below will **always** be false
    if (actionEvent.getSource().equals(individualCustomer)) {
         // .... code here
    }
}
```

you could make those if's in series:

```
if (actionEvent.getSource().equals(modifyCustomer)) {

    //.....

} else if (actionEvent.getSource().equals(individualCustomer)) {

    //.....

}
```

then it will work.

Better to give each JButton its own anonymous inner ActionListener to separate concerns

```
individualCustomer = new JButton("Individual customer");
individualCustomer.addActionListener(() -> {
    // button-specific listener code goes here
});
```

---

Regarding this code:

```
if(true){
     frame.dispose();
     System.out.println("Enter the new phone number: ");
     int updatedPhoneNumber = input.nextInt();
}
```

It looks like you're trying to mix linear console programming with Scanner and println with event-driven GUI, and that is almost always guaranteed to fail as the two paradigms don't mix well. Stick with one paradigm, here, stick with getting all input via the GUI in an event-driven way, and delete all Scanner code based on System.in.

---

One last thing, please do have a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)